# Fit within the screen in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to fit the pages within the screen size, even though I have considered the width as 100% and overflow-x as none the page is moving out of the screen. The space that is being moving out is the width of the sidenavbar that is present out there in left which is 80px when inactive and 380px when active. What can be done here in order to fit everything within screensize. I have attached the screenshots to get an idea.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would recommend wrapping your `sidebar` and `content` inside a `flex-box`. 
This way you can make your `content` element grow and fill all the space of its' parent by specifying `flex-grow: 1`.

Comment: We can better help you If you provided your code.

Comment: if you don't give us your code then how can we help?